# ValueError: substring not found on lip reading code

Tags: python

This is what I have gotten while trying to run step 3 of this source code:
https://github.com/carykh/lazykh

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\lazykh-main\code\scheduler.py", line 93, in 
> OS_nextIndex = originalScript.index(wordString,OS_IndexAt)+len(wordString)
> ValueError: substring not found

Code:

```
import argparse
import os.path
import json
import numpy as np
import random

def addPhoneme(p, t):
    global prevPhoneme
    global f
    if p != prevPhoneme:
        strings[4] += (str.format('{0:.3f}', t)+",phoneme,"+p+"\n")
    prevPhoneme = p

def pickNewPose(t):
    global pose
    global prevPose
    global POSE_COUNT
    global prevPhoneme
    global f
    newPose = -1
    while newPose == -1 or newPose == pose or newPose == prevPose:
        newPose = int(random.random()*POSE_COUNT)
    prevPose = pose
    pose = newPose
    strings[3] += (str.format('{0:.3f}', t)+",pose,"+str(pose)+"\n")
    prevPhoneme = "na"

strings = [""]*5

POSE_COUNT = 5

emotions = {}
emotions["explain"] = 0
emotions["happy"] = 1
emotions["sad"] = 2
emotions["angry"] = 3
emotions["confused"] = 4
emotions["rq"] = 5

mouthList = [["aa","a"],["ae","a"],["ah","a"],["ao","a"],["aw","au"],
["ay","ay"],["b","m"],["ch","t"],["d","t"],["dh","t"],
["eh","a"],["er","u"],["ey","ay"],["f","f"],["g","t"],
["hh","y"],["ih","a"],["iy","ay"],["jh","t"],["k","t"],
["l","y"],["m","m"],["n","t"],["ng","t"],["ow","au"],
["oy","ua"],["p","m"],["r","u"],["s","t"],["sh","t"],
["t","t"],["th","t"],["uh","u"],["uw","u"],["v","f"],
["w","u"],["y","y"],["z","t"],["zh","t"],
["oov","m"]] # For unknown phonemes, the stick figure will just have a closed mouth ("mmm")

mouths = {}
for x in mouthList:
    mouths[x[0]] = x[1]

ENDING_PHONEME = "m"
STOPPERS = [",",";",".",":","!","?"]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='blah')
parser.add_argument('--input_file', type=str,  help='the script')
args = parser.parse_args()
INPUT_FILE = args.input_file

f = open(INPUT_FILE+".txt","r+")
originalScript = f.read()
f.close()

f = open(INPUT_FILE+".json","r+")
fileData = f.read()
f.close()

data = json.loads(fileData)
WORD_COUNT = len(data['words'])

pose = -1
prevPose = -1
prevPhoneme = "na"
emotion = "0"
pararaph = 0
image = 0

OS_IndexAt = 0
pickNewPose(0)
strings[1] += "0,emotion,0\n"
strings[0] += "0,paragraph,0\n"
strings[2] += "0,image,0\n"
strings[4] += "0,phoneme,m\n"
for i in range(WORD_COUNT):
    word = data['words'][i]
    if "start" not in word:
        continue
    wordString = word["word"]
    timeStart = word["start"]

    OS_nextIndex = originalScript.index(wordString,OS_IndexAt)+len(wordString)
    if "<" in originalScript[OS_IndexAt:]:
        tagStart = originalScript.index("<",OS_IndexAt)
        tagEnd = originalScript.index(">",OS_IndexAt)
        if OS_nextIndex > tagStart and tagEnd >= OS_nextIndex:
            OS_nextIndex = originalScript.index(wordString,tagEnd)+len(wordString)
    nextDigest = originalScript[OS_IndexAt:OS_nextIndex]

    if "\n" in nextDigest and data['words'][i-1]['case'] != 'not-found-in-audio' and (prevPhoneme == "a" or prevPhoneme == "f" or prevPhoneme == "u" or prevPhoneme == "y"):
        addPhoneme("m", data['words'][i-1]["end"])

    """print(wordString)
    print(str(OS_IndexAt)+", "+str(OS_nextIndex))
    print(nextDigest)
    print("")"""
    pickedPose = False
    for stopper in STOPPERS:
        if stopper in nextDigest:
            pickNewPose(timeStart)
            pickedPose = True

    if "<" in nextDigest:
        leftIndex = nextDigest.index("<")+1
        rightIndex = nextDigest.index(">")
        emotion = emotions[nextDigest[leftIndex:rightIndex]]
        strings[1] += (str.format('{0:.3f}', timeStart)+",emotion,"+str(emotion)+"\n")
        prevPhoneme = "na"

    if "\n\n" in nextDigest:
        pararaph += 1
        image += 1 # The line of the script advances 2 lines whenever we hit a /n/n.
        strings[0] += (str.format('{0:.3f}', timeStart)+",paragraph,"+str(pararaph)+"\n")
        prevPhoneme = "na"

    if "\n" in nextDigest:
        image += 1
        strings[2] += (str.format('{0:.3f}', timeStart)+",image,"+str(image)+"\n")
        prevPhoneme = "na"
        if not pickedPose:
            pickNewPose(timeStart) # A new image means we also need to have a new pose



    phones = word["phones"]
    timeAt = timeStart
    for phone in phones:
        timeAt += phone["duration"]
        phoneString = phone["phone"]
        if phoneString == "sil":
            truePhone = "m"
        else:
            truePhone = mouths[phoneString[:phoneString.index("_")]]
        if len(truePhone) == 2:
            addPhoneme(truePhone[0], timeAt-phone["duration"])
            addPhoneme(truePhone[1], timeAt-phone["duration"]*0.5)
        else:
            addPhoneme(truePhone, timeAt-phone["duration"])
    OS_IndexAt = OS_nextIndex

f = open(INPUT_FILE+"_schedule.csv","w+")
for i in range(len(strings)):
    f.write(strings[i])
    if i < len(strings)-1:
        f.write("SECTION\n")
f.flush()
f.close()
print(f"Done creating schedule for {INPUT_FILE}.")
```

Comment: We don't know what `originalScript` contains. Please create a [mcve]. For example, If `INPUT_FILE+".txt"` is empty, then you cannot index a string of its contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

> ValueError: substring not found

occurs when you try to find the index of a substring in a string which does not contain it in the specified (or default) section, using the `index` function.

The `index` method takes 3 parameters:

- `value`
- `start`
- `end`

and it searches for the `value` between `start` and `end`.

So, the error occurred because the substring was not found in the section where it was searched for. The line of

```
OS_nextIndex = originalScript.index(wordString,tagEnd)+len(wordString)
```

searches for `wordString`, starting from `tagEnd` and searches for the likes of

```
<span>yourwordstring</span>
```

, but in your case it was not found. You can do one of the following to solve the issue:

- you can fix your input if it should always have a match for the search
- you can handle the error when the index throws the error
- you can use `find` instead, see https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-valueerror-substring-not-found

Note that `find` also has three parameters, as you can read from https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp